# minWidth not working in spark containers flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, flex4.5

I have a panel and i have set minWidth and width for it. The code looks like this    `<s:Panel id="adg1" x="199" y="164" width="200" minWidth="300" title="Title">`
Here the expected behaviour is width of the panel should be 300 since the minWidth > width,but the panel width is 200.I dont understand where i have went wrong.Any ideas...

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HAve you looked into the PanelSkin class? There is a minWidth property set to 131. That's probably why the width is set to 200.

Try to remove the minWidth property of the skin and look if it changed something or not

Comment: @Florian F hey thanks, where do i find the panel skin class i have not used any skins for this, if you are telling the default skin class where do i find that..

Comment: @Florian F can you give some example for the same?

Comment: 2 solutions: Ctrl+Shift+T or create a new Custom skin based on PanelSkin

Comment: @Florian F ok i have changed the skin class, I created a custom skin and i changed the minWidth value in the spark skin tag,but it is not working,correct me if i did something wrong.  '<s:Panel id="adg1" x="146" y="164" width="50" title="Title" skinClass="panelSkin">'  here the width is only 50, but the minWidth value in the skin is 100.

Comment: @Florian F ok just take a look at the code I have given width="50" in s:Panel tag and in the skin class i have given minWidth as 100. so my panel width should be 100 as it is the minWidth, but the panel width is 50

Comment: @Florian F The point is why the minWidth value is not taking effect when the width value is less than the minWidth value.That is what im not understanding.Hope now you dont have trouble.Thanks for replying

Comment: @Florian F I got it working,I changed the minWidth value on contentGroup in the skin class.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the size of a component is always set by the container's parent.  A component never sets its own size.  MXML can mask this a bit.

I would expect an explicit width (AKA `width="200"` ) to override any minWidth value that you set.  Since you set an explicitWidth to 200; I don't think minWidth will ever be considered.  But, you'd have to look specifically at the layout code for the container which contains your Panel.